# Axios/Vue/Nuxt - Find out when all API calls are finished

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I want to make several API calls to get data into a component. I created a `PostService.ts` that looks like this:

```js
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api/v1',
})

export default {
  async getPosts() {
    const { data }: { data: Post[] } = await apiClient.get('/posts')
    // transform data ...
    return data
  },
  async getTags() {
    const { data }: { data: Tag[] } = await apiClient.get('/tags')
    return data
  },
  async getComments() {
    const { data }: { data: Comment[] } = await apiClient.get('/comments')
    return data
  },
}
```

This is my posts.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="dataLoaded">
     content
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      loading...
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
finishedApiCalls = 0

get dataLoaded() {
    return this.finishedApiCalls === 3
  }

created() {
    PostService.getPosts()
      .then((posts) => {
        this.posts = posts
        this.finishedApiCalls++
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('There was an error:', error)
      })
    PostService.getTags()
      .then((tags) => {
        this.tags = tags
        this.finishedApiCalls++
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('There was an error:', error)
      })
    PostService.getComments()
      .then((comments) => {
        this.comments = comments
        this.finishedApiCalls++
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('There was an error:', error)
      })
  }
</script>
```

The key point is that I want to display a loading spinner as long as the data has not been loaded. Is it recommended to make the API calls from `created()`? What would be a more elegant way to find out when all calls are finished? It does not feel right to use the `finishedApiCalls` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Nuxt's [`fetch`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch) method along with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on all your async `PostService` fetches:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  fetch() {
    return Promise.all([
      PostService.getPosts().then((posts) => ...).catch((error) => ...),
      PostService.getTags().then((tags) => ...).catch((error) => ...),
      PostService.getComments().then((comments) => ...).catch((error) => ...)
    ])
  }
}
```

Nuxt provides a [`$fetchState.pending`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch#when-to-use-fetch) prop that you could use for [conditionally rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) a loader:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Loading v-if="$fetchState.pending" />
    <div v-else>My component data<div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have got a similar answer from the Nuxt Community Discord, so I will go for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all` for this kind of requirements.

```
this.loading = true
Promise.all([PostService.getPosts(), PostService.getTags(), PostService.getComments()])
   .then(values => {
      let [posts, tags, comments] = values
      this.posts = posts
      this.tags = tags
      this.comments = comments
      //Here you can toggle your fetching flag like below
      this.loading = false
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all()`. This will wait till all resolves or if 1 fails.

With `async / await` you can make it "synchronous"

```
 data() {
    return {
       loaded: false
    }
 },
 async created() {
    let [posts, tags, comments] = await Promise.all([PostService.getPosts(), PostService.getTags(), PostService.getComments()])
    this.posts = posts;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.loaded = true;
  }
```